# How to grab the YouTube thumbnail from the YouTube url?

Tags: reactjs, youtube, youtube-api

I want to include YouTube thumbnail inside my react app.

I already made enable the YouTube v3 api in `developers google`

so here is the request I am making

[https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jypIrxqhXo&key=`HEREISTHEKEY`](https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jypIrxqhXo&key=%60HEREISTHEKEY%60)

The thing is The data coming back doesn't have the thumbsmail image data. What am I missing here , what change I have to make to get the thumbnail data back

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `part=snippet` as an url [parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search):

> The snippet object contains basic details about a search result, such as its title or description. For example, if the search result is a video, then the title will be the video's title and the description will be the video's description.

So your url should look like this:

`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jypIrxqhXo&part=snippet&key=YOURKEY`